# Passing derived object to the method which accepts base class

Tags: c#, .net

I' m passing object of derived type(SuperCar) to the method that accepts object of base type(Car). After casting (Car) to the derived object(SuperCar) values are still preserved (program prints out 4).

I' wondering if I do *downcasting* why *upcasting* preserves values? How is that called in a C#?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SuperCar superCar = new SuperCar(); 
        DoTheJob(superCar);
    }

    static void DoTheJob(Car car)
    {
        Console.Write(((SuperCar)car).Doors);  // prints 4
        Console.Read();
    }
}


abstract class Car
{
    public int Wheels { get; set; }
}

class SuperCar : Car
{
    public SuperCar()
    {
        Doors = 4;
    }

    public int Doors { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

Casting doesn't change the object.  It just changes how the compiler *sees* the object.  When you cast from `SuperCar` to `Car` - all you're doing is telling the compiler that "this is a `Car`.  Treat it as such.".  It's *still* a `SuperCar` in reality, but the compiler doesn't *know* that.

When you *upcast*, you're telling the compiler that "this is a `SuperCar`".  If it is, then the cast works just fine.  If it's *not*, then the runtime detects that you are saying it is a type that it's not, and throws an error.